# Hive extract data from Nested Array

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services, hive, amazon-athena

Hi need to extract data from an **array of array**, Im using Athena

```
create external table test
(
customer string
)
Location 'something-something'
```

The single row of this table is,

`select * from customer limit 1`

```
{ "ID": "XXXX", "USerDate": { "items": [{ "Name": "Nir", "CLG": "NPT", "Place": "CBE", "Any Group": {}, "Interest": { "items": [{ "Games": "Cricket", "Music": "AR" }] }, "Others": {} }] } }
```

I need to extract the row as like

| ID  | Name | Place | Games| Music |

|-----|---------|----------|----------|-----------|

Comment: "USerDate"? .....

Comment: Please supply data example where the arrays have multiple elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select  json_extract_scalar(customer,'$.ID')    as ID
       ,json_extract_scalar(i1.item,'$.Name')   as Name
       ,json_extract_scalar(i1.item,'$.Place')  as Place
       ,json_extract_scalar(i2.item,'$.Games')  as Games
       ,json_extract_scalar(i2.item,'$.Music')  as Music

from    test

        cross join unnest (cast(json_extract(customer,'$.USerDate.items') 
            as array(json))) as i1 (item)

        cross join unnest (cast(json_extract(i1.item,'$.Interest.items')
            as array(json))) as i2 (item)
;
```

---

```
  ID  | Name | Place |  Games  | Music
------+------+-------+---------+-------
 XXXX | Nir  | CBE   | Cricket | AR
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer